# Realizar calculo em comando SQL

Tags: sql, query, select

Realizei um comando de `select` em minha tabela `estoque` onde eu trago o **modelo do suprimento**, sua **quantidade atual** e qual é a sua **quantidade minima** no estoque, para isso fiz a `query` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT
  codigosuprimento,
  suprimento,
  count (codigosuprimento) quantidade,
  estoqueminimo
FROM
  public.estoque,
  public.suprimento
where
  usado = '0' and 
  public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo
group by
  codigosuprimento,
  suprimento,
  estoqueminimo
order by suprimento
```

É possível realizar um calculo nessa `query` para trazer o saldo desse suprimento, para isso eu faria a conta `quantidade - estoqueminimo`, isso é possível?

Comment: SELECT codigosuprimento, suprimento, count (codigosuprimento) quantidade, estoqueminimo, (SUM(quantidade) - estoqueminimo) AS saldo
FROM public.estoque, public.suprimento where usado = '0' and 
public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo group by codigosuprimento, suprimento, estoqueminimo order by suprimento;

Comment: qual a necessidade do `SUM`?

Comment: O SQL não tem funções para subtracção apenas soma

Comment: O `quantidade` é o resultado do meu `COUNT` não consigo utilizá-lo. `ERROR:  column "quantidade" does not exist`

Comment: Ok não percebi isso, deixa-me ver...

Comment: seu saldo de estoque vai ser uma contagem do codigosuprimento ?

Comment: Postei minha resposta @RovannLinhalis

Comment: Não testei, mas tenta assim -> SELECT codigosuprimento, suprimento, SUM ((SELECT count (codigosuprimento) FROM estoque)-estoqueminimo) as saldo
FROM public.estoque, public.suprimento 
where usado = '0' 
and public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo group by codigosuprimento, suprimento, estoqueminimo order by suprimento;

Comment: eu perguntei apenas uma questão de modelagem... seu saldo do estoque é uma contagem do codigosuprimento ? ou seja, cada item que adicionar no estoque é único, isso mesmo ?

Comment: @HelderPereira postei uma resposta com o modo que atendeu minha necessidade

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, sim cada item é único, pois ele entra com o seu número de série

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri como retornar o que preciso, precisei apenas alterar uma parte da `query`, no fim ela fica assim:

```
SELECT 
    codigosuprimento,
    suprimento,
    count (codigosuprimento) quantidadeAtual,
    estoqueminimo,
    (count (codigosuprimento) - estoqueminimo) quantidadeSaldo
FROM
    public.estoque,
    public.suprimento
where
    usado = '0' and 
    public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo
group by
   codigosuprimento,
   suprimento,
   estoqueminimo
order by suprimento;
```

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos